# saving csv file to s3 using boto3

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3

I am trying to write and save a CSV file to a specific folder in s3 (exist).
this is my code:

```
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

csv_buffer = BytesIO()

bucket = 'bucketName/folder/'
filename = "test3.csv"
df.to_csv(csv_buffer)
content = csv_buffer.getvalue()

def to_s3(bucket,filename,content):
  s3.Object(bucket,filename).put(Body=content)

to_s3(bucket,filename,content)
```

this is the error that I get:

```
Invalid bucket name "bucketName/folder/": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$"
```

I also tried :

```
bucket = bucketName/folder
```

and:

```
bucket = bucketName
key = folder/
s3.Object(bucket,key,filename).put(Body=content)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
def to_s3(bucket,filename, content):
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    k = "folder/subfolder"+filename
    client.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=k, Body=content)
```

Comment: where do I put the content?

Comment: so how it will save content as a csv file?

Comment: Oh sorry you need to replace the filename with file.

Answer (score 9):

Saving into s3 buckets can be also done with `upload_file` with an existing .csv file:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = 'bucket_name'
filename = 'file_name.csv'
s3.meta.client.upload_file(Filename = filename, Bucket= bucket, Key = filename)
```

Comment: why 2 filename?

Comment: First parameter is the directory of the file and the second one is the name of the key to upload to. (See the descriptions of parameters here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
bucket = bucketName
key = f"{folder}/{filename}"
csv_buffer=StringIO()
df.to_csv(csv_buffer)
content = csv_buffer.getvalue()
s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Body=content,Key=key)
```

AWS bucket names are not allowed to have slashes ("/"), which should be part of Key. AWS uses slashes to show "virtual" folders in the dashboard.
Since csv is a text file I'm using StringIO instead of BytesIO

Comment: are you instantiating the s3_client or s3_resource here?

Comment: sorry, I'm using boto3 client:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import boto3
from io import StringIO

from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv("/path/to/.env", override=True)


def df_to_s3(df, bucket, key):
    # Create a session
    session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=os.environ.get("AWS_SECRETS_PROFILE_NAME"))
    aws_s3_client = session.client(
        service_name="s3",
        region_name=os.environ.get("AWS_SECRETS_REGION_NAME"),
    )

    # Create a CSV string from the DataFrame
    csv_buffer = StringIO()
    df.to_csv(csv_buffer, index=False)

    # Put the CSV string to S3
    aws_s3_client.put_object(
        Body=csv_buffer.getvalue(),
        Bucket=bucket,
        Key=key
    )
    print(f'Successfully put DataFrame to {bucket}/{key}')
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
df_to_s3(df, 'bucketName/folder/', 'test3.csv')
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: @TheTridentGuy Happy to: anything specific you want me to elaborate on?

Comment: Why it works, what you changed, etc.