# Unable to save a preprocessed data as csv to a folder in s3 bucket

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have the following tree structure of my folder:

```
.
├── All_seasons_combined_script.py
├── Base_SLP
│   ├── G0.xlsx
│   ├── G1.xlsx
│   ├── G2.xlsx
│   ├── G3.xlsx
│   ├── G4.xlsx
│   ├── G5.xlsx
│   ├── G6.xlsx
│   ├── H0.xlsx
│   ├── L0.xlsx
│   ├── L1.xlsx
│   └── L2.xlsx
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── slp_handler.py
```

I have the following code in `slp_handler.py`:

```
def yearly_slp_handler(event, context):
    try:
        COUNTRY = event['country']
        currentYear = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y")
        HOLIDAYS = get_holidays(currentYear, COUNTRY)

        excel_path = os.path.join(Path(), "Base_SLP")
        print(excel_path)
        os.chdir(excel_path)

        absolute_path = Path(os.path.abspath(
            os.path.dirname('Base_SLP'))).parent
        print(absolute_path)

        EXCEL_FILES = glob.glob('*.xlsx')
        print(EXCEL_FILES)

        for file in EXCEL_FILES:
            time_series_df = season_df(file, HOLIDAYS)
            save_name = file.split('.')[0] + '_' + \
                currentYear + '_timeseries.csv'

            time_series_df.to_csv(save_name, index=None)

            s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
            bucket_name = 'mybucket/folder'
            s3.meta.client.upload_file(
                Filename=save_name, Bucket=bucket_name, Key=save_name)

            print('CSV dropped in the bucket folder.')

        return {'Status': 200}

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return {'Status': 400}
```

where `get_holidays` & `season_df` are a couple of functions I have for pre-processing the data.

What I am trying to do is to read all the `excel` files in the `Base_SLP` folder, pre-process each of them and save them as `csv` using `to_csv` in a folder in the s3 bucket.

When I deploy the code as `lambda` and test it, it gives me the following error:

```
START RequestId: xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx Version: $LATEST
./Base_SLP
/var/task
['G0.xlsx', 'G1.xlsx', 'G2.xlsx', 'G3.xlsx', 'G4.xlsx', 'G5.xlsx', 'G6.xlsx', 'H0.xlsx', 'L0.xlsx', 'L1.xlsx', 'L2.xlsx']
[Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'G0_2020_timeseries.csv'
```

I want the preprocessed file to be converted into a `csv` and then this `csv` must be dropped in a folder in the s3 bucket. I tried the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54161768/11135962) by onur, but it is still not working.

I also tried saving the `csv` in the `/tmp/` folder and them uploading it from there to the folder in s3 using [S3.Object.upload_file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.upload_file):

```
for file in EXCEL_FILES:
  time_series_df = season_df(file, HOLIDAYS)
  save_name = file.split('.')[0] + '_' + \
      currentYear + '_timeseries.csv'

  time_series_df.to_csv('/tmp/' + save_name, index=None)
  print('DF converted to CSV.')

  saving_file_path = os.path.join('folder', save_name)
  print(saving_file_path)

  # Create S3 object
  s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
  s3.Object('mybucket', 'folder').upload_file(
      '/tmp/' + save_name)
  print('CSV dropped in the bucket folder.')

return {'Status': 200}
```

but it was throwing the following error:

```
Failed to upload /tmp/G0_2020_timeseries.csv to mybucket/folder/G0_2020_timeseries.csv: An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the PutObject operation: The specified bucket does not exist
```

The bucket and the folder exist and have public access. But still, it is throwing this error.

My `lambda` has the `AmazonS3FullAccess` access attached to it.

What is the mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to save your files in `/var/task`. In lambda environment, only `/tmp` is writable to your function.

Therefore, you could trying the following:

```
            save_name = '/tmp/' + file.split('.')[0] + '_' + \
                currentYear + '_timeseries.csv'
```

Comment: Hey @Marcin, thank you for your help. I tried your suggestion in the method 1 and it throws the following error now: `Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name "mybucket/folder": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$" or be an ARN matching the regex "^arn:(aws).*:s3:[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}$"`

Comment: @Junkrat Hi. The bucket name should be "mybucket", without the "/folder". If you want to place your files in some folder, this should be part of your save key name. For example `s3.Object('mybucket', 'folder/<your_file_name>').upload_file('/tmp/' + save_name)`